# Combining Estimates from Conditional Quantile Regression : Meta-analysis?

Tags: regression-coefficients, meta-analysis, quantile-regression

Suppose i have several studies (e.g 5) and i use conditional quantile regression (e.g using the package `quantreg` in R) to obtain conditional quantile estimates at several percentiles (e.g 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, ... 0.9) using the same model ($y=B_1x_1 + B_2x_2 + e$) in each study. Can i combine estimates at each percentile (separately) from the different studies using meta analysis, assigning random effect to the study from which the estimate was obtained?

I've [read](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80349/what-is-the-difference-between-conditional-and-unconditional-quantile-regression) that conditional quantile regression cannot be generalized to the population, however doesn't random effects meta-analysis assess variance attributed to differences in sampling populations by definition?

Comment: This paper by Rob Hyndman suggests an approach along the lines of what you seem to be asking for, *Forecasting Uncertainty in Electricity Smart Meter Data by Boosting Additive Quantile Regression*. Available here ... http://robjhyndman.com/papers/smart-meter-quantiles.pdf

Comment: It is an interesting paper and i thank you for sharing it. However, it does not seem to answer the question of whether conventional meta-analysis can be used to combine conditional quantile regression estimates in the same way as OLS estimates can be combined

Comment: Is it possible you're being a tad rigid in your definition of meta-analysis?

Comment: Its more than possible, ill take a closer look, and apologize for my ignorance

Comment: No worries...we're all here to learn.

Comment: I am not an expert in quantile regression but if the estimates have a variance-covariance matrix available then I would have thought multivariate meta-analysis might be what you are looking for.

Comment: thats an interesting idea, they do come with variance covariance matrix. I'm just not entirely confident that conditional quantile regression estimates from different studies can be combined at all....